# Change data source of several Pivot tables stored in the same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, pivot-table

my problem is the following : I have a data source in sheets("Source") that I update time over time, so that the number of lines is increasing. I want to automatically update the Pivotables linked to this data source, in sheets("Overview") trhough a vba code. In Sheets ("Overview") there are 2 Pivot tables as well as plots.

Here is the code :

---

```
Sub UpdatePivotTableRange()

Dim Data_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Pivot_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim StartPoint As Range
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim PivotName1 As String
Dim PivotName2 As String
Dim NewRange As String
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

'Set Pivot Table & Source Worksheet
Set Data_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
Set Pivot_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview")

'Enter in Pivot Table Name
PivotName1 = "PivotTable1"
PivotName2 = "PivoTable2"

'Defining Staring Point & Dynamic Range
Data_Sheet.Activate
Set StartPoint = Data_Sheet.Range("A1")
LastCol = StartPoint.End(xlToRight).Column
DownCell = StartPoint.End(xlDown).Row
Set DataRange = Data_Sheet.Range(StartPoint, Cells(DownCell, LastCol))
NewRange = Data_Sheet.Name & "!" & DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Change Pivot Tables Data Source Range Address
Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName1). _
ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange)

Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName2). _
ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange)

'Ensure Pivot Table is Refreshed
Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName1).RefreshTable
Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName2).RefreshTable

'Complete Message
Pivot_Sheet.Activate
MsgBox "Your Pivot Table is now updated."

End Sub
```

---

I get the following errors :

- either "Run-time error'5': Invalid procedure call or argument" or;
- "Run-time error '1004': The Pivot Table field name is not valid".

Can you help please ?

Regards,
Leopold
`

Comment: Why do you need to use a VBA code ? You could just declare your data source as a table (let's say ```DataTable```), and use it to build the 2 pivot tables. So adding data in the ```Source``` sheet means adding a row in ```DataTable```, which would automatically update the 2 pivot tables.

Comment: If you need VBA code you may look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522749/updating-data-source-on-multiple-pivot-tables-within-excel?rq=1) which is pretty similar to yours and has already been answered.

Comment: Hi @Vincent, I would prefer using a VBA code. I tried the code mentioned in the link you shared, but I still have the same problem when it comes to "ChangePivotCache"...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the address of the cell, you can apply the range area directly.

```
Sub UpdatePivotTableRange()

    Dim Data_Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim Pivot_Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim StartPoint As Range
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim PivotName1 As String
    Dim PivotName2 As String
    Dim NewRange As String
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim Pv As PivotTable
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim pvFD As PivotField

    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    'Set Pivot Table & Source Worksheet
    Set Data_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
    Set Pivot_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview")


    'Enter in Pivot Table Name
    PivotName1 = "PivotTable1"
    PivotName2 = "PivoTable2"

    'Defining Staring Point & Dynamic Range
    Data_Sheet.Activate
    Set StartPoint = Data_Sheet.Range("A1")
    LastCol = StartPoint.End(xlToRight).Column
    DownCell = StartPoint.End(xlDown).Row

    With Data_Sheet
        Set DataRange = .Range(StartPoint, .Cells(DownCell, LastCol))
        'Set DataRange = StartPoint.CurrentRegion   '<~~ same upper line
    End With
    'NewRange = Data_Sheet.Name & "!" & DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

    'Change Pivot Tables Data Source Range Address
    Set Pv = Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName1)
    With Pv
        .ChangePivotCache Wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataRange) '<~~ directly apply range object
        .ClearTable '<~~ This is necessary because the item does not reflect well as it increases.
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
        .RefreshTable
    End With
    Set pvFD = Pv.PivotFields("id")
    With pvFD
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    Set pvFD = Pv.PivotFields("name")
    With pvFD
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    Set pvFD = Pv.PivotFields("id")
    With pvFD
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    Set pvFD = Pv.CalculatedFields.Add("Mysum", Formula:="q1-q2")
    With pvFD
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 1
    End With



    Set Pv = Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName2)
    With Pv
        .ChangePivotCache Wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataRange) '<~~ directly apply range object
        .ClearTable '<~~ This is necessary because the item does not reflect well as it increases.
        .RowAxisLayout xlOutlineRow
        .RefreshTable
    End With
    Set pvFD = Pv.PivotFields("id")
    With pvFD
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    Set pvFD = Pv.PivotFields("name")
    With pvFD
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    Set pvFD = Pv.PivotFields("id")
    With pvFD
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    Set pvFD = Pv.CalculatedFields.Add("Mymutiply", Formula:="q1*q2")
    With pvFD
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    Pivot_Sheet.Activate
    MsgBox "Your Pivot Table is now updated."

End Sub
```

### Data Sheet

[image]

### Pivot Sheet

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is still there : when it comes to ".ChangePivotCache Wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataRange) ", a run-time error '1004' occurs.

Comment: @leopold.p Try to add a breakpoint before updating the 1st pivot table, and check if every value is as expected. You can also add ```DataRange.Select``` in your code just to have a visual check over the range you actually work with (which should fit your source data table).

Comment: Sorry to ask the question @leopold.p, but did you spell your PivotTable names correctly ? Because the first is ```PivotName1 = "PivotTable1"``` but the second is ```PivotName2 = "PivoTable2"```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not coming from this missing letter. I run the macro in Debug mode so I can check every step of the code. Every time it stops to ".ChangePivotCache Wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataRange)". As you mentioned, I checked DataRange and this part is fine, it selects the range I want to use.

Comment: I think I found the root cause : because I wanted to create measures directly into the Pivot Table by adding columns (example create a column that calculate the ratio between two columns : number of hours / number of day to get the hours/day ratio), I checked the checkbock "Add this data to the Data Model" when creating the Pivot Table (in the pop-up window, at the bottom), which is Excel DAX (I don't really know what it is). I think this is the problem because I created a new pivot table without this option, and it works well.

Comment: Is there a way to update thourgh VBA, Pivot Tables with this option (Excel DAX) ? If it is not possible, how can I add measures with excel formulas into the Pivot Table (Calculated fields?) ? Thank you :)

Comment: @leopold.p, I added CalculatedFields example.

Comment: Thank you @Dy.Lee and Vincent for your help :)