# Add Multiple Values to Multiple Pivots

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, named-ranges

I'm a novice and haven't been able to piece together anything I've searched for into a solution. Any help is appreciated.

### Data Set

I have a large number of pivot tables in a worksheet. Each of the pivot tables is sourced by a single very large table (over 1,000 columns and thousands of rows). Each pivot table provides a specific insight.

This data set is unfortunately poorly designed which I have no control over and limits my approach.

### Objective

I would like to refresh the values in the pivot tables as needed. Each pivot table may have a few values to add, while some pivots may have dozens of values to add.

I'm trying to avoid searching for and adding multiple data elements in the pivot table field listing containing well over a thousand elements and doing that for dozens of pivot tables each time this report needs to be refreshed.

An example of what I'm looking for is below. The good news is that the list of values that I need in each individual pivot is set in a named range. So for the table below, I have a named range "Pivot1_List" that includes [Value3,Value5,Value6]. There are named ranges for each of the pivots I need to populate.

### Example

| Pivot1 | Pivot2 | Pivot3 | Pivot4 | Pivot5 | Pivot6 | Pivot7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value3 | Value2 | Value1 | Value17 | Value421 | Value81 | Value101 |
| Value5 | Value10 | Value51 |  | Value422 | Value84 | Value102 |
| Value6 | Value11 | Value52 |  | Value423 | Value85 | Value103 |
|  | Value23 | Value53 |  | Value424 |  | Value104 |
|  | Value24 | Value54 |  | Value425 |  | Value105 |
|  | Value25 | Value55 |  |  |  | Value1001 |
|  |  | Value56 |  |  |  | Value1002 |

### Solutions Tried

I mentioned I'm a novice so I haven't gotten very far with anything. I've tried to add the name of the named range above the pivot to use as a reference. I don't know enough about PowerPivot to know if that's a viable solution. I initially thought perhaps not given that the data set each pivot references is the same.

This is probably an ineffective approach. I'm not sure how to reference the name of the named range that's populated above each pivot. I figure offset will work, but I can't get it to work. And I'm not sure how to reference the values for each named range.

```
Dim s as Worksheet
Dim pt as PivotTable
Dim pf as PivotField

Set s = ActiveSheet
For each pt in s
Then
pt.AddDataField.'not sure how to add named range values'
Exit For
```

I hope this isn't too confusing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you just need to update the table with data that has been added to the source you just call `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll`. If you want specific pivot tables to refresh, thats `Sheets("SheetName").PivotTables("Table Name").RefreshTable`

Comment: To reference the columns of a pivot table, you can use `PivotTables("Table Name").PivotFields("Column Name")` . From there you can get the data range, or individual pivot table cells.

Comment: If you need to change the data source (Add or remove columns or rows) of a pivot table, see [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522749/updating-data-source-on-multiple-pivot-tables-within-excel?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks Toddleson. The crux of my problem is that each time the report is refreshed all of the "set" values in the pivot table are subject to change. So using Pivot1 from the example in the table above, the next time I run the report the set of values could be completely different than [Value3,Value5,Value6].

I thought that the set of values being stored as named ranges might help.

I thought it was possible to bring in a named range into a pivot table, which would bring in all of the associated values, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Are the Value1, Value2  etc column headings and what type of calculations are they sum,count,average or all different ?

Comment: CDP1802, yes, the values are column headings. The calculations the pivots perform will be various, but I think most or all will be sum, count, or average.

I could have sworn that at one point I drug a named range from the pivot table list into the Rows field listing and the values from that named range populated within the pivot table, but I can't reproduce that. If I could, then that would work for my solution.

Comment: For my solution to work you would need to expand your named ranges to 2 columns, one column for heading and the next column the calculation ie sum, average,count etc  would that be possible ?

Comment: CDP1802, I might be able to make that work, but I might need to fiddle around with some existing VBA. So from my example above for the first named ranged you're thinking (column, row): ["Pivot1", "Value3", "Pivot1", "Value5", "Pivot1", "Value6"] ?

Comment: Thinking about it you could keep the table as it is but add the calculation type with a separator.So "Value1" becomes "Value1?Sum" or "Value1?Avg" etc. Its easy to separate them in the code.